# Positioning Vue Gallery Slideshow in the center of the screen

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

I use  https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gallery-slideshow

```js
    <template>
        <div>
            <img class="image" v-for="(image, i) in images"   :src="image" @click="index = i">
            <vue-gallery-slideshow :images="images" :index="index" @close="index = null" style="top:25% !important; width:80%; height: 80%"></vue-gallery-slideshow>
        </div>
    </template>
```

But the window looks like this.[enter image description here][1]
How do I position this element in the center of the screen?

I delete all style settings and now I hame: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iw8p.jpg)

How do I position an element centered?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/61qXr.png

```
Ib browser I can set 
    .vgs__container{
     top:15%
    }
```

But in .vue  file is not work. I don't undestend why browser not see it.

Comment: Show your `style`

Comment: I edit qwestion.

Comment: Complete these interactive tutorials to learn the basics of viewing and changing a page's CSS using Chrome DevTools.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Comment: Try to delete    `.image {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `class="image"` may conflict with `class="image"` vue-gallery-slideshow.
Try to replace your `class="image"` for example `class="image2"`

Comment: I rename class image, It not help.

Comment: try to manually add padding to the div using style = ""

Comment: <div style = "padding-top: 15%">

Comment: I switched to Lingallery. It turned out to be simpler and does not have this problem